# Unfinished large panel opening in outside wall

Tags: stucco, hole-repair, pet-door

This house was built in 2015. I am the 2nd owner. I am unsure what this opening  is/was meant for. (*see photos*)

Somebody might have meant to install a panel and then had a change of heart. There are 4 anchors that suggests someone meant to attach some sort of a metallic cover, but it is not there. This looks like unfinished work. As far as I can tell, everything is functioning properly in my house.

Can anybody help make sense of this, and suggest remediation?

Shall I simply apply some stucco on the existing concrete boards?

(*I am unsure what is best in term of water and pest proofing, but surely there is room for improvement!*)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's an old cat door opening

Comment: What's on the other side?

Comment: I just looked and yes the drywall was patched up. So it seems like the opening was meant to go through the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put some sheet vinyl in there to act as a moisture barrier and then reinstall one of those cement boards into the opening. Then get some stucco mesh and attach it to the cement board and then apply the stucco. It might take a layer or two to bring it to the right thickness. Once the top coat has been completed, run a shallow nap paint roller over the area to try and match the texture. You might have to practice that a bit.
I agree with @jsotola .... sure looks like a cat or doggie door.